# Save value from readonly field in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

I have 3 fields on form field sum is readonly. After click on Save data from readonly field is not store in database.

Example:

```
class myClass(models.Model):

number_1 = fields.Integer(store=True,default=0)
number_2 = fields.Integer(store=True,default=0)
sum = fields.Integer(store=True)

@api.onchange('number_1','number_2')
def compute_sum(self):
    total = self.number_1 + self.number_2
    self.sum = total
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer a computed field in this situation. Readonly fields won't be saved by formular changes (for example on change events). In Odoo 11 there was introduced a new option `force_save` for this behaviour in views, but previous versions don't have this option (except with community modules e. g. [web_readonly_bypass by OCA](https://github.com/OCA/web/tree/9daf14c02477499070201aab08e1cbcdc6a3ba0e/web_readonly_bypass)).

The solution for computed fields:

```py
class myClass(models.Model):

    number_1 = fields.Integer()
    number_2 = fields.Integer()
    sum = fields.Integer(compute="compute_sum", store=True)

    @api.depends('number_1','number_2')
    @api.multi
    def compute_sum(self):
        for record in self:
            total = record.number_1 + record.number_2
            record.sum = total
```

There is no need for view definition changes. And there also is no need for `store` parameter in normal `Integer` fields. Default value `0` is already the default on `Integer` so ne need to define it.

You don't have to explictly define `readonly` in the view for `sum` because a computed field without inverse method is readonly by default.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code will help you

In my case have Total year field is readonly and based on 'Date of birth' Total year will be update

Using onchange method, Can get Total year on field but when save that record Total Year field to set blank

Solution:-

Create new dummy field of total year and set that dummy field value on original field

Example:-

Python file

total_year = fields.Float()

total_year_copy = fields.Float()

from datetime import date​​

## Onchange method

@api.onchange('dob')
def onchange_dob(self):
today = date.today()
self.total_year = self.total_year_copy = today.year - dob.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (dob.month, dob.day))

## Create method

@api.model

def create(self, vals):

if 'total_year_copy' in vals:

vals.update({'total_year': vals.get('total_year_copy')})

return super(Project, self).create(vals)

## Write method

@api.multi

def write(self, vals):

if 'total_year_copy' in vals:

vals.update({'total_year': vals.get('total_year_copy')})

return super(Project, self).write(vals)

Xml File

field name="total_year" readonly="1"

field name="total_year_copy" invisible="1"

Hope this help you to save readonly records

Best Regards,

Ankit H Gandhi

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 0):

```
from openerp import models, fields, api,exceptions

class your_model(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'your.model'

    field_1 =fields.Many2one('model.a', required="True", string="Field 1")
    field_2 = fields.Integer(string = 'Field 2')

    # onchange of field_1 we are populating value in field_2

    @api.onchange('field_1')
    def _onchange_field_1(self):
        if field_1:
            # your logic goes here to get value for field_2
            self.field_2 = some_value

    # As we know that when we get the value on onchange method, 
    # the desired field convert into readonly mode and its value does not save into the database
    # to save the value into the database we are going to override create and write method and in that method we explicitly save the value

    @api.model
    def create(self,vals):
        if self.field_2:
            vals['field_2']=self.field_1
        res = super(your_model, self).create(vals)
        return res

    @api.multi
    def write(self,vals):
        if not self.field_2:
            vals['field_2'] = self.field_1
        res = super(your_model, self).write(vals)
        return res
```

Reference: [Save readonly field value in database](https://learnopenerp.blogspot.com/2021/10/onchange-method-readonly-field-not-store-database-odoo.html)